# fancyhdr top page number

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using following commands for page number in the upper right corner `0.5` inch from the top and `1` inch from the right edge of the paper. How to update the below mentioned command to get  that setting.

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
}
```

Comment: If it is only page number, there are other easy methods like `eso-pic` and `background` etc. Are you interested?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please complete your code snippet to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  Solutions will depend on your documentclass and how you set-up page dimensions.

Comment: @HarishKumar Better then nothing i guess, do you want to answer?

Comment: @HarishKumar I bet this one will get into the *answer the unanswered* queue tomorrow/tonight.

Comment: @Johannes_B Answer added.

Answer (score 3):

While you have many options like `eso-pic` etc, here is one with `background` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\backgroundsetup{
        position=current page.north east,
        nodeanchor=north east,
        hshift=-1in,            
        vshift=-0.5in,
        angle=0,
        firstpage=true,
        scale=1,
        opacity=1,
        color=black,
        contents={\thepage},
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \kant[1-100]
\end{document}
```

[image]